# Chrome extension click input type='file' not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

A web page have a input tag in html.

```
<input id='custon_btn_img_upload' type='file' onchange='upload_image(this.files[0])'>
```

My Chrome Extension will click this input to upload file.

code:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "HELPER",
  "description": "HELPER",
  "version": "0.1",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://LOCALHOST/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

myscript.js

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { // delete key 27
        $('#custon_btn_img_upload').click();
    }
});
```

It does not working at chrome extension.

But the code work at chrome browser developer console.

What is the problem?

Comment: Where is that code?

Comment: What's a `LOCALHOST`? I think the URLs are case-sensitive so it should be `localhost`. Anyway, start by properly debugging the content script in devtools: open its Sources panel, Content script, find yours, set breakpoints and reload the page, then press Esc and see what happens.